# Dataproc cluster underlying VMs using default service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc, terraform-provider-gcp

I created a Dataproc cluster using a service account via a Terraform script. The cluster has 1 master and 2 workers, so three Compute Engine instances got created as a part of this cluster creations. My questions are-

1. Why these VMs have default service accounts? Shouldn't they use the same service account that I used to create the dataproc cluster?

Edited: Removed one question as suggested in comment (as topic became too broad)

Comment: You should limit your post to one question per post. In your case you are asking two different questions and the second one is asking for opinions on security which is both off topic and too broad. Split your questions into two posts to have a better chance of getting good answers.

Comment: #1 is somewhat complicated and its explained here: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/iam/dataproc-principals

Comment: @JohnHanley, you are right. Done

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts) is how you can specify the service account used by the cluster VMs. If you are sure they still use the default service account, it might be a mistake in the Terraform script. You can test with gcloud without Terraform to confirm.

Comment: You are right @Dagang. It was a mistake in the script. My bad. I have not tried gcloud yet. I'll need to check it out.

Comment: I also wanted to make 'can_ip_forward' and block site wide ssh keys as False, but there I could not find the option to do that - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dataproc_cluster 
Do you know of any other way to enable these two? Many thanks for your help with terraform

Comment: Also want to make 'Shielded VM' as true. I don't think this is possible via Terraform script for Dataproc. Can you please provide your inputs here?